# What's are some reliable ways to identify suspicious logins?

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, ip

I'm interested in implementing a feature on my web application that warns users when a suspicious log in has occurred since their last visit.

My kneejerk reaction was to use the client's IP address, but after doing my research it seems like this is a terrible idea. Dynamic allocation and NAT suggest that this is not reliable.

My second thought was to use a geolocation service. But the ones I could find were either IP-based or outside of my price-range.

My third thought was to implement something like Facebook's "Register this device" prompt, but I'm unsure how this works in a reliable way.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could identify a device or location with a reasonable level of confidence?

Comment: IMHO, the easiest approach would be to display something like "Last login at 12:34 PM MST on 12/23/2012", and -- maybe -- if the IP addresses don't match, append " from IP 10.20.30.40" and let the user decide if there's been any suspicious activity.

Comment: use cookies in the browser

Comment: Not sure is this is allowed here to mention a commercial product (which I have just used, no other connection) but maxmind.com have a raange of geoIP products and anti frud ones that may be of help, if you do not already know them

Comment: Attempting to log in as several usernames with the same password (usually the obvious 'password' or the site's name),  in quick succession sometimes from the same IP but usually not.

Comment: @BobKaufman I like the idea of "Last login," but my userbase is not technical -- at all. Ideally, I'd like abstract the "from" a bit from them. Maybe just a time and date would be enough? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on your business rules. You could score it based on several factors.

1. Not the same IP: +5
2. Not the same subnet: +10
3. Not the same Country: +100
4. 3 or more attempts before success: +50
5. 2 or more logins at the same time: +50
6. Different browser than last time: +5

etc.

Then you could setup rules that say:

1. 0-20: Tell the user on their next successful login.
2. 21-50: Start making them wait 5 minutes between logins.
3. 51-100: Lock the account and force them to unlock it via email confirmation.

I would always show them the last date and IP of login like gmail does. Gmail also has a login history you can view.

Edit:
This is a really old answer that still gets some views. Today I'd probably recommend a 2FA solution. [What is two-factor authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559639/what-is-two-factor-authentication)